# Java - Possible to create a parent class object that can store an instance of any subclass?

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance

I know an array of a parent class can store an instance of any it's sub-classes but is this possible with a single object:

Here's an example of what I'm hoping to understand:

```
public class Parent
{
    int a;
    
    public Parent(int a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }
    
    public void function1()
    {
        //Actions
    }   
}

public class Child1 extends Parent
{
    public Child1(int a)
    {
        super(a);
    }
    
    public void function2()
    {
        //Actions
    }
}

public class Child2 extends Parent
{
    public Child2(int a)
    {
        super(a);
    }
    
    public void function3()
    {
        //Actions
    }
}
```

Now if I perform the following:

```
Parent p1;

Child1 c1 = new Child1(5)

p1 = c1;

p1.function1();

p1.function2();
```

Would I be able to run the the `function1` method of the `Parent` class as well as the`function2` method of the `Child1` class  with the `Parent` class object `p1`?

Sorry if this is a silly question. I'm new to all this. Also, if this is a duplicate and you mark it as such, I'd appreciate that too.

Comment: Try to compile your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more trial and error and additional research, I realize that what I'm hoping to achieve is not possible.

As such, for my project I created separate instances of each class and accessed them individually when required. That wasn't the solution I had in mind but it served as an effective workaround to my problem.

PS: To the comment that pointed out this code wouldn't work, they are right, it doesn't. It was meant as an abstract example to illustrate my issue. But perhaps I shouldn't have formatted it as a code then. I'll change that right away.